# Does any one know about this painting?

Tags: virgin-mary, art

Can some one let me know about the picture?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any information about, perhaps where you saw it?

Comment: Google Image search isn't much help. "Best guess for this image: *mother.* Mother! (stylized as mother!) is a 2017 American psychological horror film written and directed by Darren Aronofsky, and starring Jennifer Lawrence..."

Comment: It's a picture. Mary is wearing blue and red? Baby Jesus is smiling but has a crooked face. What exactly do you want to know about it?

Comment: I can let you know that it kind-of looks silly compared to more traditional icons.

Comment: @curiousdanni: it’s just a random forward I got. I want to know if it’s some famous painting - a collectible sort

Comment: Possibly done  by a French artist as the ND stands for Notre Dame (Our Lady).

Comment: It appears to be [a painting by Navya Davis](http://ml.naradanews.com/category/page-3/navya-davis-pictures-of-jesus-and-mary-with-smiling-faces-go-viral-535047), who claims portraying Mary and Jesus smiling is an innovation, and that the Bible 'doesn't say they didn't smile.' It's the only hit on Google.

Comment: @SolaGratia This is clearly the correct answer. I can't find it in English on the site nor get a complete translation. How could it have "gone viral" if we can't find it elsewhere on the Internet?

Comment: While the painting is a good attempt ( though one would suspect that Mary has been modelled after a famous Bollywood heroine Priety Zinta),  there is nothing innovative with the concept . The humour of Jesus has been a subject of discussion in this forum.

Comment: @SolaGratia Can you please make that an answer?

Answer (score 5):

Doing a [reverse image search](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1325808?hl=en) on Google, it appears to be [a painting by Navya Davis](http://ml.naradanews.com/category/page-3/navya-davis-pictures-of-jesus-and-mary-with-smiling-faces-go-viral-535047), who claims *portraying* Mary and Jesus smiling is an innovation, and that the Bible 'doesn't say they didn't smile' (according to the article by Sachin Sunny).

Comment: Excellent googling! I figured the ND would get somewhere, I didn't know about the reverse image search though - that's great.